# How to change pressed Tab color in TabRow in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple Jetpack Compose TabRow example on Kotlin from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#tabrow), where I just changed a text and underline color. But there is an orange background color when the tab is pressed. I want to make it transparent.

[image: Image of TabRow]

```
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val titles = listOf("TOP", "NEW", "HOT")
Column {
    TabRow(
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant, // This is underline's color
        selectedTabIndex = state
    ) {
        titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                text = { Text(title) },
                selected = state == index,
                onClick = { state = index }
            )
        }
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        text = "Text tab ${state + 1} selected",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
    )
}
```

Comment: I probably need to change **interactionSource** field of Tab

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If by pressed color, you are referring to this tab,

[image]

This is created by the `Tab`'s ripple color.

This color would be affected by the `selectedContentColor` attribute in `Tab`.
But, even if you specify `Transparent` you would see a greyish ripple effect.

Modify the attribute to match with the closes satisfiable color as required.

---

The code creating the ripple effect.

```
// The color of the Ripple should always the selected color, as we want to show the color
// before the item is considered selected, and hence before the new contentColor is
// provided by TabTransition.
val ripple = rememberRipple(bounded = true, color = selectedContentColor)
```

As this is an internal implementation detail, we cannot disable it. ()

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can set `backgroundColor` for tabs like this:

```kotlin
TabRow(
   selectedTabIndex = state,
   ...
   backgroundColor = Color.White
)
```